Solving a problem or an equation related to complex numbers
Let $m$ be an integer satisfying $m > 1$. Determine the solution of the following equation within the field of complex numbers:
$$
(z-i)^m + (z+i)^m = 0
$$
Note:
$z$ is a complex number.
I worked on this equation up to the following stage and couldn't proceed further:
It can be stated that our equation can also be expressed as:
$$(z-i)^m = -(z+i)^m$$
Therefore, for two complex numbers raised to a power to be equal, their magnitudes must be the same. In other words:
$$ |z-i|^m = |z+i|^m $$

What have you tried?

Include in a question what u have tried to solve a problem

@Guruprasad Done.

@Lorago Edited. I provided additional explanations.

Continue. If $a^m=b^m$, then $a=b$ (when $a,b>0$). Next, what useful identities do you know about $|z|$?

Instead of taking magnitudes I'd try dividing, and proceeding from there.

One may also take the $m$th multivalued root

Hint: $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ is a $m$-th root of $-1$.

Notice that $z\in \mathbb C$ can only be a solution when $z \neq i$, otherwise the LHS of the equation becomes $(-2i)^m \neq 0$. Let now $z\in \mathbb C\setminus\{i\}$. We have the following chain of equivalences:
$$\begin{align*}(z−i)^m+(z+i)^m=0 &\Longleftrightarrow (z−i)^m = -(z+i)^m\\& \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{z-i}{z+i} \right)^m = -1 \\& \Longleftrightarrow\exists k\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}, \quad \frac{z-i}{z+i} = e^{\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{m}}\\& \Longleftrightarrow\exists k\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}, \quad z-i = e^{\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{m}}(z+i)\\& \Longleftrightarrow\exists k\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}, \quad z = i\cdot\frac{1+e^{\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{m}}}{1-e^{\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{m}}}.\end{align*}$$
The third equivalence comes from the fact that the $m$-th roots of $a = re^{i \theta}$ (written in polar form, $r>0$, $\theta \in \mathbb R$) are given by $r^{\frac 1m}e^{\frac{i\theta}{m}}\omega^k$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}}$ for $k\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$. The last equivalence is true because $1-e^{\frac{i\pi(1+2k)}{m}}\neq 0$ for any $k\in \{0,\dots,m-1\}$.
